# How to parse a jsonObject or Array in Java

Tags: java, android, json

I have an API request from my CRM that can either return a jsonObject if there is only one result, or a jsonArray if there are multiple results. Here are what they look like in JSON Viewer

JsonObject:

[image]

JsonArray:

[image]

Before you answer, this is not my design, it's my CRM's design, I don't have any control over it, and yes, I don't like how it is designed either. The only reason I am not storing the records in my own database and just parsing that, which would be MUCH easier, is because my account is having issues not running some workflows that would allow me to auto add the records. Is there any way to figure out if the result is an object or an array using java? This is for an android app by the way, I need it to display the records on the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `OPT` command instead of `GET`

```
JSONObject potentialObject=response.getJsonObject("resuslt")
.getJsonObject("Potentials");

// here use opt. if the object is null, it means its not the type you specified
JSONObject row=potentialObject.optJsonObject("row");
if(row==null){
    // row is json array .
    JSONArray rowArray=potentialObject.getJsonArray("row");
    // do whatever you like with rowArray
} else {
    // row is json object. do whatever you like with it
}
```

Comment: Perfect! This is what I was looking for. All of the other methods I tried would just duplicate one record multiple times. Thanks a bunch for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**ONE**

You can use `instanceof` keyword to check the instances as in

```
        if(json instanceof JSONObject){
            System.out.println("object");
        }else
            System.out.println("array");
```

**TWO**

**BUT** I think a better way to do this is choose to use only `JSONArray` so that the format of your results can be predicated and catered for. `JSONArray`s can contain `JSONObject`s. That is they can cover the scope of `JSONObject`.

For example when you get the response (either in a `JSONObject` or a `JSONArray`), you need to store that in an instance. What instance are you going to store it in? So to avoid issues use `JSONArray` to store the response and provide statements to handle that.

**THREE**
**Also you can try method overloading in java** or **Generics**

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way is to use Moshi, so that you dont have to parse, even in the case of the Model changing later, you have to change your pojo and it will work.

Here is the snippet from readme

```
String json = ...;

Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
JsonAdapter<BlackjackHand> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(BlackjackHand.class);

BlackjackHand blackjackHand = jsonAdapter.fromJson(json);
System.out.println(blackjackHand);
```

https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/README.md